# How to I recompile an extracted pyinstaller file back to exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, recompile

I've decompiled a pyinstaller exe using pyinstrxtctor and i have no clue how to recompile it back to an exe.

I've tried using the .spec file but no luck with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.